# How to use case statement in where clase

Tags: mysql

i want to write case statement in where clause in which i want to select record from table property_master except code='2' if request_type as input from procedure is 1
my procedure syntax is

```
create PROCEDURE test101 (IN request_type int)
begin
  select code from property_master where code=case when request_type=1 then code else 4 end;
end;
```

i want something like this

```
select * from property_master where code=case when request_type=1 then code <> '2'
```

in that request_type value i am getting from stored procedure as input 
so my intention is select all code from table except 2

Comment: You almost never use `case` in `where` clauses. Use simple boolean logic. Please add an example and expected output

Comment: See here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845171/run-a-query-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure-if-a-condition-is-true

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just need some boolean logic, and you might need to combine some conditions using parentheses such as this:

```
select * from property_master
where code='1'
OR (request_type=1 AND code <> '2')
```

Comment: exactly what i want
i also achieved same by 
select code from property_master where code <> case when request_type=1 then 2 else code end;

Comment: by this also i am getting same result
 select * from property_master
  where (request_type=1 AND code <> '2');
then 1) why there is need to add code='1' in where clause
2) even if i wrote code='2' also i am able to get same result. why?