# How to create a SQL statement that only return the result if one of the row contain the desired value?

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

My goal is to return the admins list only if the requester's username is registered as admin / member in that channel.

I store the admins and members list in TABLE `channel_member`.

```
CREATE TABLE channel_member (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, // '0' = admin, '1' = member
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

What I've tried:

1. This SELECT statement return multiple row regardless whether the `username` exists as `admin` or `member`.

```
  @Select("SELECT user_detail.user, user_detail.name " +
          "FROM user_detail " +
          "JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} AND channel_member.role='0'")
  List<MemberModel> getChannelAdmins(String username, String channelUuid);
```

What I am thinking what the logic would look like but don't know how to write it into a SELECT statement:

1. Get the TABLE `user_detail`
2. Get the TABLE `channel_member`
3. JOIN table `user_detail` and `channel_member` / get intersection that:

   1. channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid}
   2. channel_member_role='0' // for admin.
4. **(I don't know how) return the result only if channel_member.user=#{username} found in one of the row.**

**TL:DR, I will post the data down below and the expected result**

Table user_detail

```
id | user       | name
1  | admin      | admin client
2  | member     | member client
3  | member-2   | member 2 client
4  | non-member | non member client
```

Table channel_member

```
id | uuid | user     | role
1  | 1    | admin    | 0
2  | 1    | member   | 1
3  | 1    | member-2 | 1
4  | 2    | admin    | 0
```

The query is `(username, channelUuid)` e.g `(member-2, 1)` to get the Admins list.

My expected result is

```
[
  {
    user: "admin",
    name: "admin client",
  },
]
```

Another query is `(non-member, 1)`

My expected result is

```
[]
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas Hi, I've added the query that I would use to clarify it better. I hope that helps.

Comment: Your query takes only 1 parameter: `#{channelUuid}`, so how do you pass user: `'member-2'`?

Comment: @forpas the current SELECT SQL statement I gave above did not care about the `username` / in other words, everyone can get the `channel detail` regardless whether the user is a member or not. I wish to change that without the need to send 3 query `1. check whether the user is a member / admin in that channel` and then `2. query to get the list of admin of that channel` and then `3. query to get the list of member of that channel`.

Comment: @forpas I am trying to do it step by step, right now I am trying to solve the problem where `everyone can get the admin list of a channel, although he is not a member`

Comment: Table relationship not clear to me. Why is user field in both tables? What is purpose of uuid field - foreign key? Are there only two roles?

Comment: Apply filter criteria to return admin records but I think whether or not to present output to user must be a separate determination. Perhaps MySQL stored procedure coding could have an IIf() or Case to first determine requestor status and based on that result, run appropriate SELECT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a query in a MySQL stored procedure if a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845171/run-a-query-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure-if-a-condition-is-true)