# SQL Trigger @@ROWCOUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I supposed to make an sql trigger for update that will only activate when the affected rows are greater than 0. Yet, Even though the affected row is 0 (or the new record is identical to the old record) it still fires the trigger. I want to check the number of affected rows, before i execute the insert query below. Thanks in advance! Sorry for my grammar!

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `dbase`.`table_update_trigger`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `table_update_trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `table` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) THEN
INSERT INTO 
    table_audit_trail
    (column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5,
    column100) 
VALUES
    (old.column1,
    old.column2,
    old.column3,
    old.column4,
    old.column5,
    old.column100);
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What does "doesn't go well" mean? Please edit the question to say exactly what happens and what you want to happen.

Comment: I'm not that up on MySQL, but I'd have thought a trigger defined as `FOR EACH ROW` would only fire... if there are affected rows. If there are no affected rows, how many times would this trigger fire?

Comment: I read your question, but sadly it doesn't go well.  Please help me with this!  *(By giving error messages, documenting expected and unexpected behaviour, etc, etc.  We're not psychic, sorry.)*

Comment: sorry for my grammar, i modify my question to be more precise on what i want to happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `@@ROWCOUNT` in MySQL.
You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229218/what-is-mysql-version-of-rowcount) to find ount how to replace it.

But you dont need that. Your trigger is `for each row` so it will fire for every updated row. (But that doesnt mean that your rows have changed. Just that they were updated by some statement.)

Comment: Oh i see, but what if i don't know the query executed? yet i want to know if there are changes that made.

Comment: Compare each column between `old` and `new`

Comment: well that's my first choice but, i have 400 columns to compare. Is there another way to check if there are changes? Thanks!

Comment: read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed)

Comment: i try adding column ts, type timestamp and not null, However, this column doesn't change whenever I'm updating a record. Im using SQLyog Enterprise in executing my query.