# MySQL how to store FOUND_ROWS() in a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get the total number of rows returned by my query before I limit it. I'm attempting to use the advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229218/what-is-mysql-version-of-rowcount), which uses: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and then `FOUND_ROWS()` in a second query;

They give this example:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS( ) ;
```

What I can't figure out is how to capture the second value from `FOUND_ROWS()` into a PHP variable. I'm working within Wordpress, so I'm using the global $wpdb to handle MySQL interactions. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever;" );
$count = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();" );
```

The first query works, but $count is always empty. If I run them both in phpMyAdmin, the queries run without error.

I've also tried this:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever;
SET @count = FOUND_ROWS();" );
```

...but it fails entirely.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you binding the actual value from the return object? What php mysql class are you using?.

Comment: have you tried it as 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, FOUND_ROWS() AS NUMOFROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever;
'

Comment: Does `$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();" );` get you an error?

Comment: what about using [$wpdb->query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database) instead which should return an integer of the selected rows?

Comment: @32bitfloat: that worked. Nice idea. This will work as a backup if I can't get the FOUNT_ROWS() to work. I suspect that should be slightly faster, right?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: I turns out that yes, it does: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' at line 8]

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: I haven't tried that yet...

Comment: @Hiroto: I'm using this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @Emerson - can you try it?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan It didn't work... `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' FOUND_ROWS() AS NUMOFROWS FROM wsat_ib' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, FOUND_ROWS() AS NUMOFROWS FROM wsat_ib;

`

Comment: sry I cannot say which is the fastest alternative. You may want to check that by using microtime(true) before and after the methods and compare.

Comment: @Emerson - sorry for bother, but the problem is that I can't test. anyway. can you try adding it like this 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ,(SELECT FOUND_ROWS() )' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is Wordpress, you could do alternatively for the second statement, otherwise you were asking for an array an not the number:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
```

Also take care that the database class of wordpress is open to change of any query due to filters *and* it suppresses errors by default doing the query and fetching from the resultset.

You should enable screaming to see if you run into specific errors.

- `$wpdb->show_errors = true` shows errors automatically, if `WP_DEBUG` is set to `true`. ([ref](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16382/178))

Comment: This works too. How does this compare to @32bitfloat's idea in the comments above? I'm mostly interested in performance. I also notice query() returns and int while get_var() returns a string.

Comment: @Emerson: Read the manual, you should aim for understanding why query returns an int and get_var not from code: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb - might look a bit much to read, just check these two methods after reading the introduction.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I'm familiar with those methods. I just mentioned it to point it out for future readers. My real concern is the performance issue. Originally I was trying to avoid making another query just to get the total rows, and so now that I am doing this, I'm trying to figure out the smartest way to do it.

Comment: Which issue do you have with the performance? Something is slow for you?

Comment: There is no problem currently, but this project needs to be able to hold thousands and thousands of results, so I'm trying to make a smart plan from the beginning. In other words, it doesn't feel slow when it's just me on my development server with a small test DB. But I want to make sure I'm not going to have problems later when it goes live for hundreds of users with a huge db. Maybe it's still fine, but I'm not very experienced with optimizing MySQL so it's something I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Use this:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total;
```

And get it in PHP:

```
echo $query[0]->total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(1) AS rowcount
FROM table
```