# Is @@ROWCOUNT after UPDATE reliably a measure of *matching* rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does `@@ROWCOUNT` reliably tell you how many rows *matched* the `WHERE` clause in an `UPDATE`, as opposed to how many where actually *changed* by it?

In [the documentation for `@@ROWCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187316.aspx) it says:

> Data manipulation language (DML) statements set the `@@ROWCOUNT` value to the number of rows **affected** by the query and return that value to the client.

*(My emphasis.)*

But if I have

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo] ([a] INT, [b] INT)
GO
INSERT INTO [Foo] ([a], [b]) VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 2)
GO
UPDATE [Foo] SET [b] = 1 WHERE [a] = 1
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
GO
```

...I see `3` (the number of rows matching `[a] = 1`), not `2` (the number of rows modified by the `UPDATE` — one of the three rows already had the value `1` for `b`). This seems like an odd definition of "affected" (not *wrong*, just at odds with how I'd normally use the word — it's actually quite handy for what I want to do, in fact).

(The similar MySQL [`ROW_COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function, for instance, would return `2` in this situation.)

Is this reliable behavior, ideally documented somewhere I just haven't found? Or are there odd edge cases...

**To be clear:** I'm not asking if `3` is the *right* answer. I'm asking if it's a **reliable** answer, or are there edge cases where SQL Server will leave out rows that matched but didn't require a change.

**Update**: A couple of people have asked (or hinted at) what kind of "reliability" issues I'm worried about. The fact is they're quite nebulous, but, I don't know, replication? Transactions? Partitioning? Indexes it could use to avoid seeking to rows because it knows that `b` is already `1`, and so it skips those? ...?

**Update**: I was hoping for someone with a more "insider" view of how SQL Server works to answer this question, but it looks like the triggers example (and others I've played with) [by xacinay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954719/157247) is as close as we're going to get. And it seems pretty darned solid; if it behaves that way in the normal case and it didn't behave that way despite partitioning or whatsit, as someone said, surely that would qualify as a bug. It's just empirical rather than academic.

Comment: The documentation does not say sometimes Returns the number of rows affected.  In SQL's eye the row was affected because it assigned a value of 1.  It did not care if a value of 1 was already there.  You may have done it to throw a trigger.

Comment: It will always report the number of rows for which it performed the `SET` operations - but, of course, that doesn't mean that it's done what you *expected*, so we'd probably need a clearer idea of what this "reliability" characteristic you're looking for is going to be used for. E.g. if the `where` was `x IN (1,2,3)` and you got a row count of 3, and you *expected* that each `x` only occurred once but in fact it updated 3 rows where `x` was equal to `2` and there were no rows where `x` equalled `1` or `3`, could that in fact be an issue for you?

Comment: I suppose the genuine source of this post is MySQL's ROW_COUNT() behaviour which depends on some environment factors.

Comment: @xacinay: No, the "genuine" source of the question is the word "affected" in the documentation, as I said. I only used MySQL as an example because I happened to know it worked differently.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Nope, that wouldn't be an issue for me. :-) I figure the answer is almost certainly "Yes, it's reliable" but it would be good to hear that in the context of well-supported (ideally cited) information about how SQL Server works. I've added an update to the bottom of the question about my (quite nebulous) "reliability" question/concern.

Comment: Watch ACID ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID),[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480356.aspx)) SQL Server

Comment: @xacinay: This has nothing to do with ACID. All due respect, and thanks again for your answer which may well end up being the accepted one, but you seem to be missing the point. Edge cases in complex software happen all the time. Under-documented things happen all the time. I'm wondering whether there are issues like that with this, that's all. Your answer boils down to "I think SQL Server works like this, and that fits the observed behavior, so I'm saying it behaves like this." You may be right, but I'd be more interested in something clearly based in a deeper understanding.

Comment: And *yes*, it's very hard to prove a negative. :-)

Comment: TJ, Im totally agree with you about deeper based explanation, but SO is probably [not the best place for a common discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). The statement you posted is proved and I wish to see exact feedback from you about the problem you facing. We stand on a bit defferent lines here ;)

Comment: @xacinay: I'm really quite clear on how SO works, thanks. I'm not talking about a discussion. "Because that's how SQL Server works" is inadequate (but may have to be good enough, I won't leave the question in "unanswered" state more than a few more days); "Because that's how SQL Server works" *with citations and/or details* is what I'm looking for. I suspect if I delve deeply enough into execution plans, it's there somewhere. Thanks again for your help. I don't think we need "dicuss" this any further between the two of us. :-)

Comment: In summary you are asking if @@rowcount is deterministic. Really?

Comment: @Blam: If you want to misread it that way, sure, go ahead. That's not what I asked, but given your answer below, well, we're not going to have any meeting of the minds on it. FWIW, though, I do think that you're right about one thing: If `@@ROWCOUNT` were going to behave differently with (say) partitioning, then it's nearly guaranteed that they'd document that pretty clearly.

Comment: You are questioning deterministic.  "Just because SQL Server doesn't distinguish between rows that matched and rows that changed, it doesn't mean it's not feasible to do so."

Comment: @Blam: No, I'm not. How it's designed to handle rows that will have the same values after as they had before has exactly nothing to do with determinism. I see no point in further beating this horse. Best in all things,

Comment: "Reliably tell you" is the stated question.  Really "Reliably tell you" has nothing to do with determinism.

Comment: @Blam: Oh for crying out loud. A deterministic system can have complex inputs. I'm perfectly clear that I'm asking whether there are complex inputs here that I'm unaware of. Enough already,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54993/discussion-between-blam-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @Blam: No thank you. I have no interest in discussing this further. Best,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation for `@@ROWCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187316.aspx) is telling you the truth because 3 rows would be *reliably* affected as opposed to [MySQL's ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

> not 2 (the number of rows modified by the UPDATE — one of the three
>   rows already had the value 1 for b).

For `UPDATE` it's not important if the new and previous values are identical. It simply does what its told to: finds data source, filters rows according to provided condition, and applies 'set' changes to filtered rows.

*That's the way SQL Server works without any reservations. MySQL may work different. A row counting procedure is not a part of the SQL standard. So, you have to look before you leap for those kinds of artefacts every time you switch from one RDBMS to another.*

Some triggers to see actual update behaviour:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgFooForUpd]
ON [dbo].[Foo]
FOR UPDATE 
AS begin declare @id int;
      select @id = [a] from INSERTED;
      select * from INSERTED; end;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgFooAfterUpd]
ON [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS print 'update done for ' + cast(coalesce( @@ROWCOUNT, -1) as varchar )+'rows'
```

Comment: Thanks, but respectfully, it *does* make a difference whether rows were changed, and as I pointed out at least one other major RDBMS makes the distinction. (But that's a side-point, I'm not saying there's an issue with Microsoft's [apparent] definition.)

Comment: This makes sense to me because you are only saying update where a = 1, not where a = 1 and b <> 1

Comment: I would have to say that the @@ROWCOUNT = 3 in your example above is correct. These would be set operations and in that regard you would expect the 3 rows with [a] = 1 to simply have their [b] column overwritten regardless of whether the value is the same before and after. The alternative would impact performance by requiring a comparison operation at each potential update - why would you do that? How would that possibly deal with floating point numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the update -- what do you mean "without any accents"?

Comment: Wel, i meant 'proviso' or 'reservation' in other words :) SQL Server reliably works the way we found out. If there are any premisses to doubt it, you should probably post them explicitly.

Comment: I agree - without `and b <> 1` in your where clause, 3 makes perfect sense. This is from a 'logical' perspective. I don't care what pages/rows/files etc. were affected. If there are smarts to not update a row if nothing is really changed, fine.... but logically, three rows were updated.

Answer (score 12):

To expand on xacinay's answer because he is correct.

You have 3 rows changed and therefore `@@ROWCOUNT` is accurate.
The SQL Server changes all rows, it does not verify that a value is in fact different before changing it, as that would require a lot of overhead on update commands.
Just imagining having to check a VARCHAR(MAX) for whether the value was actually changed or not.

The easiest way to illustrate this is to actually change yor UPDATE query to something like this:

```
UPDATE [Foo]  SET [b] = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.b
WHERE [a] = 1
```

It will output 3 rows of `INSERTED` which is the 'pseudo' table that holds the new values for a given update/insert command.
That the value in fact is already b = 1 in one instance does not matter.

If you want that to matter you'll need to include it in your `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE [Foo]  SET [b] = 1
WHERE [a] = 1 AND [b] <> 1
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Alternatively, and as a more general way of doing this check, you can make a trigger and compare the values/fields in the `DELETED` table with the values in the `INSERTED` table and use that as foundation for whether a row is actually 'changed'.

So - 3 is the accurate number as you have updated 3 rows because 3 rows were touched by `[a] = 1`

Comment: I have to admit, this is the most valueable answer here :)

Comment: I'm not asking whether it's *right*, I'm asking whether it's *reliable*. (And again: Just because SQL Server doesn't distinguish between rows that matched and rows that *changed*, it doesn't mean it's not feasible to do so. MySQL does, for instance, as I pointed out in the question.)

Comment: I've extended my answer, hoping it satisfies your genuine question more

Comment: Please be aware that the second code block (with [b] <> 1) is not the same as the original code block.  The first code block would set the b column value to 1 whether it was some other number or null.  This second code block would not update the b column value if the original value was null.  To accommodate the null situation, it should be "Where a = 1 and (b <> 1 or b is null)"

Comment: That's correct, but seeing as none of the data was null to begin with and it's simply an example that if you don't want 'non-changes' in your @@rowcount then you need to filter it away yourself, so such nuances didn't seem terrible important in such a context.

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation is correct because no matter that one row in your example already had 1 as the value in `[b]`, that row **still satisfied the criteria in the `WHERE` clause so the value was 'updated'**.

We can see a proof by extending your example a little bit and including a `TIMESTAMP` column as in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4732/1). After the update the `TIMESTAMP` on all columns which were matched by the `WHERE` cluase has changed indicating that the row itself was changed and not merely assessed and discarded because the target value matched that which was already present.

Comment: I really liked your `TIMESTAMP` example, thank you for that. This is an excellent empirical proof that SQL Server works by doing the write to the row regardless of the previous value. The fact it does that shows up in `TIMESTAMP`, in triggers, and (of course) in `@@ROWCOUNT`. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In summary you are asking if @@rowcount is deterministic. Really if it was non-deterministic you don't think you would see that in the documentation?  It is reasonable to assume deterministic.  @@VERSION and @@MAX_PRECISION are also not documented as deterministic based on that are you questioning edge cases where they are not deterministic.  I seriously doubt there is an edge case that it fails but it it does then Microsoft will accept it as a bug.  They are not going to come back with @@rowcount is nondeterministic - the documentation did not explicitly state deterministic.

Numerous examples that "affected" in MMSQL TSQL counts a row set to the same value (it only cares about the where)
And you have examples that MSSQL does in fact assign the same value (timestamp)
You assert but SQL could care so how do I do I know there is not an edge case that is does
Because that is not reasonable behavior
Any program should produce consistent output
The order without sort is not guaranteed but the rows are the same - that is specifically documented by Microsoft and SQL as nondeterministic
If @@rowcount was nondeterministic then I trust Microsoft would document that
It is reasonable to assume @@rowcount is deterministic
C# and Java do not always have the same behavior
That is not a reason for me to suspect C# and Java are not reliable

Look at the query plan in MSSQL
There is no predicate on [a]
There is a predicate on [b]

If you change the query to

```
UPDATE [Foo] SET [b] = 1 WHERE [a] <> 1 and [b] = 1;
```

Then you will see predicates on both [a] and [b]

The query optimizer will decide how most efficiently process the query it is not going to change the query.
Introducing a predicate on [b] in the first query is changing the query.
A proper database just does not do that.

I highly suspect that in MySQL if you look at the query plan there will be a predicate on [a] in the first query.

Rather than require proof that is reliable create an edge case that proves it is not reliable.
If you can create a situation it is not reliable I submit Microsoft would accept it as a bug.

What is the business case?
If you have business case that a value must be updated with same value then by definition you have something to test.
The only examples I can thing of are timestamp or trigger.
If you have true need to for an update to the same to take place then you have something to measure.
Do you have any evidence that a value is not updated to the same value?
If you still don't trust it then wrap it in a transaction.

If you don't need an update to the same value then why not just add [b] <> 1. 
That is more efficient.

SO is for specific programming question.
What is the programming question?
Prove MSSQL is reliable is not a programming question.