# Getting a row count and returning it in a variable MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, rowcount

I have a problem where I am unable to return the number of rows in this table. I get an error when trying to store the row count in a variable and also get an error when I try to return it. This is a stored function in MySQL.

I get the two errors:
1.Not allowed to return a result set from a function
2.ROW_COUNT Doesn't exist(isn't called)

Here is my code so far:

```
BEGIN

declare pageexists int;
declare rowcount int;

select distinct ITU from tblITU
where ITU = inuser; 
SET rowcount = COUNT(*) FROM tblITU;

return rowcount;

END
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> For SELECTs you can use the FOUND_ROWS construct (documented here):
>
> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS something FROM your_table WHERE whatever;
>
> SELECT FOUND_ROWS( );
>
> which will return the number of rows in the
>   last SELECT query (or if the first query has a LIMIT clause, it
>   returns the number of rows there would've been without the LIMIT).
>
> For UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT, it's the ROW_COUNT construct
>
> INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1,2,3);
>
> SELECT ROW_COUNT();
>
> which will return the number of affected rows.

Quoted from: [Does Mysql have an equivalent to @@ROWCOUNT like in mssql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229218/does-mysql-have-an-equivalent-to-rowcount-like-in-mssql)

Comment: I've tried this one. It doesn't seem to work, or I'm not using it correctly. I tried this:

BEGIN

    declare pageexists int;
    declare rowcount int;


    select distinct ITU from tblITU
    where ITUsers = inuser; 
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tblITU;
    rowcount = SELECT FOUND_ROWS( ); 


    return rowcount;

    END

Comment: This one still gives the "Not allowed to return a result set from a function " error

Comment: Sorry for that, try this: SET rowcount = (select distinct count(ITU) from tblITU where ITUsers = inuser); 
  RETURN rowcount;

Comment: Oops I forgot about the DISTINCT there. This should do it:
SET rowcount = (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM (select distinct count(ITU) from tblITU where ITUsers = inuser) AS src);

Comment: This one worked. Thanks. But I will admit, that I'm an idiot. I created a working solution two months ago, forgot I had it.